# Apply with parameter and input file redirector does not work

Tags: ant, ibm-mq

I would like to execute `runmqsc MYQMGR < myinput.mqsc` (for multiple `*.mqsc` files) like this in Ant (1.10.7):

```
<project>
    <apply executable="runmqsc" failonerror="true">
        <arg value="MYQMGR"/>
        <fileset dir="." includes="*.mqsc"/>
        <redirector>
            <inputmapper type="identity"/>
        </redirector>
    </apply>
 </project>
```

This does not work because it executes `runmqsc MYQMGR myinput.mqsc < myinput.mqsc`.

I also tried the `exec` task to execute `runmqsc` with all the input `*.mqsc` files redirected to `stdin` in one go, but it also does not work because `exec` does not allow a nested `fileset`.

Any idea how I can achieve this in Ant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add the following option:

> ### addsourcefile
>
> Whether source file names should be added to the command automatically.

```
<apply executable="runmqsc" failonerror="true" addsourcefile="false" >
   <arg value="MYQMGR"/>
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for.